# How to rank a list with multiple conditions on c#

Tags: c#, linq, console-application

I am trying to figure out how to rank a list with multiple conditions:

1. This is my list:

[image: Excel List]

2. Let me explain the list above:

> a. '**AreaCode**' is an unique ID for each group of the list.
>
> b. I will rank the list based on highest value of Rank 1 (highlighted with yellow).
>
> c. If Rank 1 has same value, I will find highest value of Rank 2 (highlighted by green).
>
> d. If Rank 2 has same value, I will find highest value of Rank 3 (highlighted by blue).
>
> e. In this case, there are same value for Rank 1 (7 and 7), so I will find the highest value for Rank 2, however the Rank 2 value also same (4 and 4), so I will find the highest value for Rank 3 (1 and 2).
>
> f. So '**Ranking**' column is the result that I want to achieve, which is a list with these value: 
>  **[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]**.

3. Last time I can do but with simple scenario (there are no Rank 1, Rank 2 or Rank 3) using this code:

   ```
   var rankings = myIndexList.GroupBy(x => x)
   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
   .Select((g, i) => new { Key = g.Key, Rank = i + 1 })
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Rank);

   var output = myIndexList.Select(x => new { Col1 = x, Rank = rankings[x] })
   .ToList();
   ```

Any ideas to achieve the result on '**Ranking**' column?

Thank You!

Comment: Your section (2) is confusing. Can you please re-explain?

Comment: I have updated the section.

Comment: One of the Rank 1 values is 8 and the other two are 7. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is. So Rank 1 is 8, 7 and 7. Rank 2 is 5, 4 and 4. Rank 3 is 3, 1 and 2.

Comment: Let's say that the first "Rank 1" were 6 and not 8.  That would cause it to be assigned a rank of 3 in the final list instead of 1, correct?   But you would also want the first "Rank 2" and "Rank 3" (in white) to be assigned a rank of 3, then, right?  So is there an ID or something that ties together each group of three ranks?  Are they all properties on a common object?  Or are they separate rows and they are grouped merely by their positioning in the original list (i.e. take every three rows and treat them as a group)?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Yes, there is an ID that ties together for each group (AreaCode). The list above is under one group with same AreaCode and there will be another groups with different AreaCode.

Comment: Okay. I will update the details.

Comment: what is the desired result of  the example above? Each `AreaCode` should map with a list of `Rankings`? The data you show looks weird to me (the repeat of `Rank1` ... in the same `AreaCode`). You should show the desired result to help others understand better (even we don't need any explanation).

Comment: what is the desired result of  the example above? Each `AreaCode` should map with a list of `Rankings`? The data you show looks weird to me (the repeat of `Rank1` ... in the same `AreaCode`). You should show the desired result to help others understand better (even we don't need any explanation).

Comment: Sorry to make you confuse, the desire result is a list with some data on **Ranking** column which is [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2].

Comment: @CoolTips2u well it's still confusing now, that's what looks exactly in the picture shown in your question so I actually assumed that's the **input**, now you said it's the **output**?

Comment: @KingKing: I have updated the list. So the input are column AreaCode, Name and Value. The output is column Ranking. So my desired result is a list with these value: [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3].

Comment: It looks like that each row (AreaCode, Name, Value) maps with 1 result of `Ranking`. So that's hard to understand what produces `Ranking` from just 3 values AreaCode, Name and Value (on 1 row). You talked about finding the highest value of `Rank1` ... but in which group we find it? (per `AreaCode` or ...?). It's very confusing indeed.

Comment: @KingKing: Okay let me explain. Each AreaCode is one group. So each group will have 1 result of Ranking. So I am finding the highest value for Rank 1 per AreaCode. However sometimes Rank 1 has same value, so I will find the highest value of Rank 2 then again, sometimes Rank 2 has same value, so I will find the highest value of Rank 3.

Comment: @CoolTips2u so each AreaCode should have one value of Ranking, that's the output but actually at first I thought you need something like this `[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]`? while actually the output (for what you posted above) should just be like this `[1,1]`. We can find that output manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159208/discussion-between-cooltips2u-and-king-king).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

/////
var list = new List<(Item Col1, int Rank)>();

var nameGroup = items.GroupBy(i => i.Name);
var sorted = nameGroup.OrderBy(i => i.Key);

foreach (var group in sorted)
{
    int ranking = 1;
    foreach (var item in group.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value))
    {
        list.Add((Col1: item, Rank: ranking++));
    }
}
```